# Connecting to redis through dash-extensions Websocket

Tags: redis, plotly-dash

Is there a way to listen to redis publisher message, through Websocket of dash-extensions package?

```
    from dash_extensions import WebSocket

    ...
    html.Div(id="message", className='p-4 border'),
    WebSocket(url='ws://127.0.0.1:6379/1', id='ws')
```

This gives error in redis-server

```
# Possible SECURITY ATTACK detected. It looks like somebody is sending POST or Host: commands to Redis. This is likely due to an attacker attempting to use Cross Protocol Scripting to compromise your Redis instance. Connection aborted.
```

Is such provision limited to specified redis clients only?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are missing a component that reads the appropriate data from the Redis server and passes them through the websocket. This could be done in many different ways. Here is a small self-contained example written purely in Python,

```
import redis
import dash_html_components as html
from gevent import sleep
from dash import Dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash_extensions import WebSocket
from dash_extensions.websockets import SocketPool, run_server


# Read data from Redis and pass it through the web socket.
def ws_handler(ws):
    while True:
        sleep(2)  # delay between updates, here 1s
        value = redis.Redis().get('foo').decode("utf-8")  # get redis value
        ws.send(f"Redis value is [{value}]")  # send data


# Inject some dummy data into Redis.
redis.Redis().set('foo', 'bar')
# Create example app.
app = Dash(prevent_initial_callbacks=True)
socket_pool = SocketPool(app, handler=ws_handler)
app.layout = html.Div([html.Div("Listening for message", id="log"), WebSocket(id="ws")])


@app.callback(Output("log", "children"), [Input("ws", "message")])
def update_graph(msg):
    return msg['data']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_server(app, port=5000)  # 5000 if the default port
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me a better and deeper idea of integrating dash and redis. However, this function can be achieved with dcc.Interval component. But I missed to mention I'm checking if I get the pubsub message in Dash, as soon as it is published from another client.

Comment: I will try changing ws_handler for pubsub.

Comment: Hi. When trying to run your example (Python 3.12, dash_extensions 1.0.14), I get :
Import "dash_extensions.websockets" could not be resolved